# Speed problems with SetValue, ToType and Reflection

Tags: c#, performance, reflection

I have a 'speed problem' with a program I'm currently developing. I already have encountered the methods which costs some time.

```
public void ConvertDataFrameToValueFields()
    {
        List<byte[]> items = new List<byte[]>() { new byte[2], new byte[2], new byte[2], new byte[2] };

        items[0][0] = this.DataBytes[0];
        items[0][1] = this.DataBytes[1];
        items[1][0] = this.DataBytes[2];
        items[1][1] = this.DataBytes[3];
        items[2][0] = this.DataBytes[4];
        items[2][1] = this.DataBytes[5];
        items[3][0] = this.DataBytes[6];
        items[3][1] = this.DataBytes[7];

        int i = 0;
        IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> result = this.determineCanMessageValueFields();

        foreach (var prop in result)
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(MessageStatusValueField))
            {
                prop.SetValue(this, new MessageStatusValueField(BitConverter.ToUInt16(items[i], 0), prop.Name, this.UnitType), null);
            }
            else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(MessageValueField))
            {
                prop.SetValue(this, new MessageValueField(BitConverter.ToUInt16(items[i], 0), prop.Name), null);
            }
            else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(MessageValueFieldInt32))
            {
                prop.SetValue(this, new MessageValueFieldInt32(BitConverter.ToUInt16(items[i], 0), prop.Name), null);
            }
            else if (prop.PropertyType.GetCustomAttributes(false).Count(x => x.GetType() == typeof(BitmaskValueFieldClass)) > 0)
            {
                var tempField = new MessageValueField(BitConverter.ToUInt16(items[i], 0), prop.Name);
                prop.SetValue(this, Convert.ChangeType(tempField, prop.PropertyType), null);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }




     private IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> determineCanMessageValueFields()
            {
                //Get all properties with the 
                //custom attribute [IsValueField]
                return this.GetType().GetProperties()
                                     .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                                     .Count(x => x.GetType() == typeof(IsValueField)) > 0)
                                     .OrderBy(x => ((IsValueField)x.GetCustomAttributes(false)[0]).ValueFieldIndex);
            }

 public object ToType(Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
        {
            //...only convert if the conversion type is a BitmaskValueFieldClass
            if (conversionType.GetCustomAttributes(false).Count(x => x.GetType() == typeof(BitmaskValueFieldClass)) == 0)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException("The conversion is only available for conversion types with the BitmaskValueFieldClass attribute");
            }

            //...create an instance of the conversion type
            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(conversionType);

            //...go thru each property and set the value
            foreach (var item in instance.GetType().BaseType.GetProperties())
            {
                item.SetValue(instance, this.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(this, null), null);
            }

            return instance;
        }
```

The method `ConvertDataFrameToValueFields()` is the sticking point. I know it is because of the `prop.SetValue()` and the `ToType() IConvertible` method calls. When I am removing the `ConvertDataFrameToValueFields()` method I gain the missing time I need to fulfill the project.

Is there a way to improve the whole thing? Problem is that the idea has to be as it is. In the `ConvertDataFrameToValueFields()` method I have to map the returning DataFrame, the DataBytes array, to the MessageValueField properties of the specific class. I'm getting all containing messagevaluefields by calling the `ConvertDataFrameToValueFields()`.

Comment: Why is speed a problem? Are you calling these methods on the same type many times? If that's the case, you might benefit from using reflection once to generate code for that type and then use that generated code repeatedly.

Comment: I also wonder what those property setters are doing. If they're not simple value settings, then perhaps the problem is not that your code is slow but that the setters it's invoking are slow. Removing the whole method would not distinguish between those cases.

Comment: could you post a working sample? may we analyse the root cause.

Answer (score 2):

**Style**

Based on the [naming guidlines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) method names should use `PascalCasing` casing.

**determineCanMessageValueFields()**

Instead of calling `Count()` and checking if it is greater than `0` you should call `Any()`.

So `determineCanMessageValueFields()` would become

```
private IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> determineCanMessageValueFields()
{
    return this.GetType().GetProperties()
                            .Where
                                (p => p.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                                            .Any(x => x.GetType() == typeof(IsValueField))
                                )
                            .OrderBy(x => ((IsValueField)x.GetCustomAttributes(false)[0]).ValueFieldIndex);
}
```

**ConvertDataFrameToValueFields()**

The creation of the `List<byte[]>` is not needed at all. If you increment the `i` counter by `2` you can just use `this.DataBytes` for the calling `BitConverter.ToUInt16(this.DataBytes,i)`.

This leads after using `Any()`instead of `Count() > 0` to

```
public void ConvertDataFrameToValueFields()
{

    int i = 0;

    foreach (var prop in DetermineCanMessageValueFields())
    {
        ushort value = BitConverter.ToUInt16(this.DataBytes, i);

        if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(MessageStatusValueField))
        {
            prop.SetValue(this, new MessageStatusValueField(value, prop.Name, this.UnitType), null);
        }
        else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(MessageValueField))
        {
            prop.SetValue(this, new MessageValueField(value, prop.Name), null);
        }
        else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(MessageValueFieldInt32))
        {
            prop.SetValue(this, new MessageValueFieldInt32(value, prop.Name), null);
        }
        else if (prop.PropertyType.GetCustomAttributes(false).Any(x => x.GetType() == typeof(BitmaskValueFieldClass)))
        {
            var tempField = new MessageValueField(value, prop.Name);
            prop.SetValue(this, Convert.ChangeType(tempField, prop.PropertyType), null);
        }

        i += 2;
    }
}
```

and applying the `Any()` change to the `ToType()` method

```
public object ToType(Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
{

    if (!conversionType.GetCustomAttributes(false).Any(x => x.GetType() == typeof(BitmaskValueFieldClass)))
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("The conversion is only available for conversion types with the BitmaskValueFieldClass attribute");
    }

    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(conversionType);

    foreach (var item in instance.GetType().BaseType.GetProperties())
    {
        item.SetValue(instance, this.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(this, null), null);
    }

    return instance;
}
```

**Comments**

Comments should be used to explain **why** something is done, not **what** is done. The **what** part should be done by the code itself.